# What is the purpose of the separating tag

Tags: xml

So I'm very much new to xml, and I found this little snippet on the web.

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <!-- This is a sample XML document -->
    <Items>
      <Item>test with a child element <more/> stuff</Item>
    </Items>
```

I understand you can put data between tags to store it in a nice manner.
I just don't get what the `<more\>` tag in the middle of the sentance is for, or what it is doing there.

Comment: To me, it is just an empty element.

Comment: It's a completely hypothetical XML document. None of the tags have any real purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<more\>` is a empty child element of the `<Item>` element. You can rewrite the above example as

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
        <!-- This is a sample XML document -->
        <Items>
          <Item>test with a child element
                <more></more>
                stuff
          </Item>
        </Items>
```

Its purpose it to show that you can mix text content and elements inside other elements.